# Would it make sense to talk about approximated constructions in euclidean geometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I got curious with something: I know that in euclidean geometry we talk about constructible and non-constructible structures, do we have the concept of approximation in euclidean geometry? I mean, we can't construct $\pi$, but we can have an approximation with the method of exhaustion - but I don't know if this method belongs to the domains of euclidean geometry, I've heard about it only on calculus.

Comment: The method of exhaustion has nothing to do with constructibility, at least not in the usual meaning of that word (compass and straightedge construction). You can construct any point of rational coordinates, so you can certainly approximate any real number to within arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between geometry and calculus in this context strikes me as  artificial; problems do not always fall into rigidly (or even not-so-rigidly) defined areas of study.

To answer your question: yes, it is meaningful, geometrically, to say "this square has the same area as this a circle to within 0.0001%", or whatever precision you want. As Jack said in the comments, you can construct lengths of arbitrary rationals, and so arbitrary approximations of reals.

A more geometric construction that doesn't "know" that $\pi\approx 3.14\dots\,$ might look like this: say you had some 1000-gon or something and you wanted to say its area was close to the area of a circle. To get a bound on the error, you would simply construct the dual 1000-gon and then calculate the difference between them (which could be done purely geometrically).